# How to name a large number of variables in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

What is the most common way of naming a large number of variables in predicate logic?

I run out of variables pretty easy in long predicate logic sentences. The simple fact of using a lot of letters as variables are hard enough, but the problem is even bigger when i run out of letters and need to use subscript numbers, as in $x_{5}$, $y_{4}$, and so on.

What is the best way of naming a lot of variables in predicate calculus, without making the sentence unintelligible?

Comment: How many is "a large number"?

Comment: The syntax of predicate logic needs countable many individual variables; thus, the simplest way to name than is with indexes : $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$

Comment: As in computer programming, try using meaningful variable names of various lengths, e.g. "first" or "last." In my proof-checking software, a variable/constant name can be a string of any length composed of letters, digits and primes as long as the first character is a lowercase letter or a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to exclusively use subscripts to distinguish the variables, e.g. $x_1,\,\cdots x_{100}$. In practice you'll probably find some subset of the variables deserve to be thought of in aggregate, so they may share a letter with each other but not other things. For example, if I stated [the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen%27s_eight-square_identity) expressing the product of two sums of eight squares as the sum of eight squares, I'd put $\sum_{i=1}^8 a_i^2\sum_{j=1}^8 b_j^2=\sum_{k=1}^8 c_k^2$ followed by explicit formulae for the $c_k$. What I wouldn't do is write $\sum_{i=1}^8 a_i^2\sum_{j=9}^{16} a_j^2=\sum_{k=17}^{24}a_k^2$.